# Cannot assign value of type 'Void' to type 'String?'

Tags: swift, string

I have an error "Cannot assign value of type 'Void' to type 'String?'"
My code

```
       func showPhone(place: Place){
           if let phone = place.phone {
            var urlPhone: NSURL = URL(string: "TEL://\(phone)")! as NSURL
            phoneValue.text = UIApplication.shared.open(urlPhone as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
           }
           else {
                self.phoneContainer.isHidden = true
           }
       }
```

Comment: Your question not clear. which line is actually throwing error.

Comment: And stop casting URL back and forward, skip NSURL altogether. `let urlPhone = URL(string: "TEL://\(phone)")!`

Comment: The error is clear: `UIApplication.shared.open` doesn’t have a return value. And URL as NSURL as URL is hilarious.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**

You're trying to assign the result of `open(_:options:completionHandler:)` as `phoneValue's` `text`. But, the method `open(_:options: completionHandler:)` doesn't return anything. That's the reason it is giving error.

**Solution:**

The `showPhone(place:)` method should be like,

```
func showPhone(place: Place){
    if let phone = place.phone {
        phoneValue.text = phone
        if let urlPhone = URL(string: "TEL://\(phone)") {
            UIApplication.shared.open(urlPhone, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
    else {
        self.phoneContainer.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I want us to be able to click on the phone link to call